# Use Zend_Paginator without loading all data from WebAPI

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

Almost similar question to here: ([how to use zend paginate without loading all the results of a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157379/how-to-use-zend-paginate-without-loading-all-the-results-of-a-database))

But in that case the question was solved by building a Table_Select to feed onto Zend_Paginator. My situation is that I am going to receive the data from a ASP.NET Web API.

The Web API have a call to return all data, or to return by pages with offset.

Any idea? I'm on Zend 1.10